# SQL Query combine two rows into one row of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (see the image below --red box). It describes the content of my table (A, B, C, and D) are the columns.  The data structure will always be like this, if col A is Type_1, only col B has a content while if Col A is Type_2, Col C and D has contents while col B is NULL.

Now, the table which re enclosed with green box is my desired output.

[image]

My experience on building a select statement is not very extensive and I'm almost leaning towards creating two separate tables to get my desired result (like 1 table for Type_1 data only and another table for Type_2 data only).

Question is, is it possible to query two rows and combine it to become a single output result using SELECT query?  Considering that these two rows are on the same table?

Thanks.

Comment: If there were multiple Type_1 and multiple Type_2 rows, how would it know which ones to combine?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, `The data structure will always be like this`

Comment: I apologize, I realized after the first comment that my image was not very clear.  Please see the updated topic.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan The data structure is the same, but data may not be.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, I told exactly about data structure.

Comment: OP, can you confirm if there is the possibility of having other records with "Type_2" or "Type_1" in it ? For example, if Table2.Id is 2 ?

Comment: If Table.Id is 2, it would be another set of Type_1, Type_2 and Type_3 with the same number of fields being filled in and number of fields being null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
  Table2Id,
  MAX(B) B,
  MAX(C) C,
  MAX(D) D
FROM tbl
WHERE A != 'Type_3'
GROUP BY Table2Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is only one row of data for type1 and one row of data for type 2, you can use the following:

```
 SELECT Id, MAX(B) AS B, MAX(C) AS C, MAX(D) AS D
   FROM Table2
  WHERE A IN ('Type_1','Type_2')
  GROUP BY Id
```

Example in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3551/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can make subqueries by enclosing them in parenthesis. As in:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 B FROM table ORDER BY some_ordering), (SELECT TOP 1 C FROM table WHERE NOT C IS NULL), D FROM table
```

The queries inside the parenthesis can apply to any table, and can use the data from the main query in calculations of the selected values and in filters.